# Grails 3 plugin using properties from application.yml

Tags: grails-plugin, grails3

I am creating a plugin using Grail 3 (3.2.11).  My plugin needs to access different properties (e.g. URLs) for each environment (e.g. development, staging, production).  When writing a Grails application I add the properties to the application.yml file.  Where do they go in the plugin?  I tried adding them to application.yml of the plugin and that does not work as expected.  If I add them to the application.yml file of the application using the plugin they work.  But I want the properties to be part of the plugin so each person who uses the plugin does not need to provide the properties.  I would expect it to work like message properties.  Where a plugin can have message properties and an application can override them by providing the same property in their local application message.properties. What am I not understanding.

Comment: Sweet that seems to work!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the same conf directory as `application.yml` you can place a `plugin.yml` (or `plugin.groovy`) which should allow you to change the plugin configuration similar to the way its done in the application's config file(s).